# Is proposing an alternative approach instead of code improvements a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I remember seeing a question which caused me to ask myself: "Why even bother writing all that code if XYZ would reliably solve that problem in a few lines?"

*Would it be a relevant answer if I proposed the XYZ-based approach?*

In my mind, the answer to this question depends on many things:

- If the question is a **puzzle/contest problem/programming exercise**, it is okay to provide an alternative *within the context of that problem* becase that's the whole point of the question. Say, commenting on a better way to select a pivot in quicksort question is fine. Proposing to use a mergesort in the same question is probably not a good idea.
- If the question is in the realms of **real project/production code** AND **the assessment criteria are NOT provided**, proposing an alternative seems to be a nice things to do because this may lead to quality/cost effects that affect end-users in real life.

Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Alternative solutions can make fine answers. You just have to justify why.

Comment: @200_success Oh boy, I did search for the duplicates and missed that one already exists!